# Single loop to get coordinates between two points

Tags: c#, algorithm

The input consists of two coordinates `(x|y)` which have the same `x` or the same `y` (meaning that they are always on the same column or row).

I'd like to get all coordinates in between.

Example input:

> (2|2), (2|5)

Example output:

> (2|2), (2|3), (2|4), (2|5)

Another example:

> (2|2), (5|2)

Example output:

> (2|2), (3|2), (4|2), (5|2)

My approach is to check for four conditions (whether `y1 > y2` or `x1 > x2` or `y1 < y2` or `x1 < x2`) and then use four **separate loops**.

Here is my pseudo-code:

```
if (x1 > x2)
    decrement x1 until x1 = x2, list all coordinates
else if (x1 < x2)
    increment x1 until x1 = x2, list all coordinates
else if (y1 > y2)
    decrement y1 until y1 = y2, list all coordinates
else if (y1 < y2)
    increment y1 until y1 = y2, list all coordinates
```

I'm looking for a way to do it in one loop though.

Comment: what language do you use? some languages really have good one liners...

Comment: @Ian I'm using C#, sorry that I forgot to put it in the question, editing it now...

Comment: I was prepared to answer "Bresenham", but this is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by finding out which of the variables needs the increase and use `max` and `min` functions in your loop:

```
int x1 = 1;
int x2 = 6;
int y1 = 3;
int y2 = 5;

int min, max;

if (x1 == x2) {
    min = Math.Min(y1,y2);
    max = Math.Max(y1,y2);
} else {
    min = Math.Min(x1,x2);
    max = Math.Max(x1,x2);
}

for (int i = min; i < max; ++i) {
    if (x1 == x2) {
        Console.WriteLine(x1 + "/" + i);
    else {
        Console.WriteLine(i + "/" + y1);
    }
}
```

Please note: I havent done C# in a long time and have no compiler here to test, so please edit the Code according to C#. Also note: If the Coordinates are the same, then the Program wont do anything, there is no error checking for that in the above code! This is just example code!